# IOS: How to import multiple photos through an API without tying up UI

Tags: ios, asynchronous, core-data

For a sync of contacts from server to handheld, I pull an array of contacts through an API and then loop through the array to save each one that is not on the handheld.

One of the fields for the contacts is the photo url and currently I grab each photo from the url and save to the handheld as I pass through that contact in the loop immediately after saving the contact.

Although I am trying to do this asynchronously, in fact, it is tying up the UI.  Specifically, after running through the importing of contacts, it begins trying to download images during which the imported contacts do not appear.  This can literally take minutes if there are many contacts to import.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do the following that does not tie up UI?

Thanks for any suggestions:

```
//loop through contacts and for each one:
 for (i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
//get ready to save to context
if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                if (![pic isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                    [self saveContactPhotos:pic];//this aves photo
}
}
-(void) saveContactPhotos:(NString *)contactpic { 
    NSString *picURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://~/pics/%@",contactpic];
    NSURL *urlPicUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:picURL];
      dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{ 
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picURL]];
        if (imgData) {
            UIImage *imageCache = [[UIImage alloc] init];
            imageCache = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            if (imageCache) { 
                 CGFloat side = 128;
                side *=[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
                UIImage *thumbnail = [imageCache createThumbnailToFillSize:CGSizeMake(side, side)];
                [self saveImage:thumbnail asPicName:picname];
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
                }); 
            }
        } 
    }); 

}
```

Comment: what is kBgQueue ?

Comment: #define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1

Comment: Looks like you're using core data. Are you interested in an alternate solution that uses main and private `NSManagedObjectContext`?

Answer (score 0):

you are updating UI on wrong thread update it under this block

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 

   // UI updates goes here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating kBGQueue?  Is it really a background queue?  What if you try using the default background queue, as in this example:

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),^{
// Do something in the background here
        }
    });`